# How to override constructor function and public variable in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

I have a custom module which overrider a Product class. This is my code:

```
class Product extends ProductCore {
    public $variable;

    public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null) {
        parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop);

        self::$definition['fields']['variable'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool');
    }

}
```

When I install the module, there is no errors. But in override folder, product.php file I don't see

```
public $variable;
```

I need to add it by myself. Where is the problem ?

Thanks for help.

-edit
This is the output of the code from below answer. Like yuo see, there is no public $variable. Why ?

```
/*
* module: mymodule
* date: 2018-06-06 15:08:01
* version: 1.0.0
*/
public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null) {
    parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop);
    self::$definition['fields']['variable'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Prestashop's coding standards for class declaration (opening and closing braces in own line) and it will parse the override properly.

```
class Product extends ProductCore
{
    public $variable;

    public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null) 
    {
        parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop);

        self::$definition['fields']['variable'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool');
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my question once again I add new results.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. To solve this problem You need to place the construct function in the first place. In the end, add declaration of variable. Like below.

class Product extends ProductCore 
{

```
public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
    {        
        parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop);
        self::$definition['fields']['variable'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool');        
    }

public $variable;
```

}

Comment: While this may work, I remember I had problems when uninstalling a module with override like this. Parser would just cut the method declaration line and leave the rest causing a fatal error in the entire shop. When I formatted the override like in my answer everything worked ok. Although it's possible they fixed it in newest 1.6 versions.